# How are GUI's for OS created

Tags: operating-system

One question that really puzzles me is how Operating systems have neat GUI, and how they are created. I have searched over Google for information on how Operating systems GUI are created. How are OS GUI's created and in what languages are they created in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GUI you're asking about isn't necessarily part of the operating system. Strictly speaking the operating system refers to the kernel, which is the software that manages hardware devices and scheduling of processes, and a user interface which may or may not involve graphics (rather than just a command line interface). Though in common parlance the "operating system" can refer to both the kernel and a GUI consisting of a windowing system and a desktop environment.

Variations of this question appear to have already been asked around Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange. See these pages:

- [What is Linux’s native GUI API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12717138/what-is-linux-s-native-gui-api)
- [How does the *NIX GUI work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035983/how-does-the-nix-gui-work)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/250375/how-does-gui-in-unix-linux-actually-work
- https://superuser.com/questions/1173074/how-do-the-componets-of-a-gui-work-in-linux